# wpf checbox and image binding

Tags: wpf, checkbox, binding

I have one image that changes depending on the status of 4 checboxes. I made the code work but it seems too long and complicated, I am new to wpf and can't make binding to work with these 4 checkboxes. Any source for help or example you can give will be great.
This is what I have right now:

```
    private void chcbox1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (chcbox1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            chcbox2.IsChecked = false;
            var02 = true;
            var01 = false;
            if (var03)
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image04.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image03.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        { 
            chcbox2.IsChecked = true;
            var02 = false;
            var01 = true;
            if (var03)
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image02.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image01.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }                
    }

    private void chcbox2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (chcbox2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            chcbox1.IsChecked = false;
            var02 = false;
            var01 = true;
            if (var03)
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image02.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image01.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            chcbox1.IsChecked = true;
            var02 = true;
            var01 = false;
            if (var03)
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image04.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image03.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }

    private void chcbox3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (chcbox3.IsChecked == true)
        {
            chcbox4.IsChecked = false;
            var04 = true;
            var03 = false;
            if (var01)
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image01.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image03.png", UriKind.Relative));                
        }
        else
        {
            chcbox4.IsChecked = true;
            var04 = false;
            var03 = true;
            if (var01)
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image02.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image04.png", UriKind.Relative));   
        }
    }

    private void chcbox4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (chcbox4.IsChecked == true)
        {
            chcbox3.IsChecked = false;
            var04 = false;
            var03 = true;
            if (var01)
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image02.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image04.png", UriKind.Relative)); 
        }
        else
        {
            chcbox3.IsChecked = true;
            var04 = true;
            var03 = false;
            if (var01)
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image01.png", UriKind.Relative));
            else
                img01.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/Image03.png", UriKind.Relative));  
        }
    }
```

checkbox1 and checkbox2 are mutually exclusive, as are checkbox3 and checkbox4
So from all the 4 combinations I get 4 different images.

Thanks for your help.
Eduardo

Comment: If you're working with mutually exclusive choices like this it's easier to use RadioButtons. Do you have a specific need for CheckBoxes?

Comment: No, no specific need, just like the looks of CheckBoxes over RadioButtons. Is easier to bind the images to radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches I can think of to simplify this.

**Use a helper method**

In all of your click handlers, the only thing you need to do is handle the mutual exclusivity aspect of the options. Updating the image appears to always be based on the same conditions. So, for example, your handler for checkbox 1 could look like this:

```
private void chcbox1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (chcbox1.IsChecked) chcbox2.IsChecked = false;
    UpdateImage();
}
```

All of the handlers can follow this same pattern, then your UpdateImage method would figure out what image to show based on the state of the checkboxes.

**Use MVVM (and a helper method)**

*If you don't know about MVVM, you should read up on it. It is the design pattern that WPF was built for.*

If you create a viewmodel class (that implements INotifyPropertyChanged) and set it as the data context for your control, you can bind the IsChecked property of each checkbox to properties in the viewmodel. You would also bind the Source property of the Image control to a property in the view model.

Here is an example partial implementation of the view model:

```
internal class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool Option1
    {
        get { return _option1; }
        set
        {
            if (_option1 != value)
            {
                _option1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();

                if (value) Option2 = false;
                UpdateImage();
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _option1;

    // Options 2, 3 and 4 basically the same as 1

    public Uri ImageUri
    {
        get { return _imageUri; }
        set
        {
            if (_imageUri != value)
            {
                _imageUri = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private Uri _imageUri;

    private void UpdateImage()
    {
        // Do logic to determine image path and set ImageUri property
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You can set this as the data context for your view in a few different ways. Probably the easiest is to do it in the constructor of your view *before* calling InitializeComponent():

```
public View()
{
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then, in the xaml for your view, you can bind the various things like this:

```
<CheckBox Content="Option 1" IsChecked="{Binding Option1}" />
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Xavier, This is what I was looking for. I will read more on MVVM. I need to learn more about binding too.